# How to retrieve text from a textedit in a CustomAlertDialog

Tags: android

Trying out the following, will result in error. How do I retrieve the values that is inputed by the user from a custom alertdialog? I did a `setText` to test if that way works.

Here is my code:

```
View categoryDetailView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.customdialoghotspot, null);

final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

b.setView(categoryDetailView);
b.setTitle("Add Current Location");
b.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
b.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

b.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind found the answer

```
    View categoryDetailView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.customdialoghotspot, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    b.setView(categoryDetailView);
    b.setTitle("Add Current Location");
    b.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

  AlertDialog a=  b.show();

    EditText editTextMemberName = (EditText)a.findViewById(R.id.txtNewText);
    editTextMemberName.setText("test");
```